# Не могу правильно строку уместить через flexbox

Tags: css3, flexbox

Здравствуйте, флейксом пользуюсь давно, но такой случай впервые и пришел через минут 20 к выводу, что не знаю как это исправить.
http://codepen.io/dimensi/pen/zNVqLa
Полагаю где-то тут кроется проблема.

```
&__title-wrapper
    padding 7px 10px
    display flex
    @extend $vertical-align-middle
    flex 0
    ^[-1]__item:hover &
        color $blue
    & .icon
        font-size 16px
        margin 0 7px
        color $black
        &:hover
            color $blue
    ~/__item--works:hover &
        color $green
        & .icon:hover
            color $green
&__title
    font-weight 600
    width auto
    overflow hidden
    text-overflow ellipsis
    white-space nowrap
    transition all 0.3s
    flex 1
```

Ладно, честно скажу, не знаю вообще где она может крыться. Я перевел список в таблицу, но легче от этого не стало. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить следующие свойства

```
.updating__type-inner{min-width: 40px}
.updating__title-wrapper{overflow: hidden;flex: 0 1 auto;}
.updating__chapter{min-width: 100px}
```

Comment: Хм, это вылечило. Но я не совсем понимаю, почему так работает. Причем работает как я хотел.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что ты не ограничил ширину строки названия.

Установи для класса `.updating__title` стиль `max-width: calc(100% - 240px);`

Comment: Не вариант. Это будет работать до тех пор когда таблица не сжата.

Comment: @DimenSi, редактировал ответ, но вижу что вам помог другой

Comment: Я предпочитаю во флексах лишний раз к calc() не прибегать. Ибо потом от него очень сильно зависит начинаешь.